# Differential vs. derivative in the Vasicek model

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, vasicek

Can anyone help me in understanding how we get the line I have marked with a red arrow?

[image]

I guess I have trouble in understanding the difference between differentials and derivatives, i.e. what is the difference between e.g., $d(e^{kt}r_t)$ and $\frac{d}{dt}e^{kt}r_t$.

Here is my thinking: $$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{kt}r_t)=e^{kt}\frac{d}{dt}r_t+ke^{kt}r_t$$

Multiplying by $dt$ yields $$d(e^{kt}r_t)=e^{kt}dr_t+ke^{kt}r_tdt$$

, which would explain everything. But I am not sure If I treat the $d$ operator properly... Also, I do not quite get how we should treat $d$ in integration in comparison to $du$ or $dw_u$. I mean, it seems like we treat $d$ as $du$ in this case so what is the difference?

Comment: Your thinking is correct, the author of the paper you quote decided to re-write $e^{kt}dr_t+ke^{kt}r_tdt$ as $d(e^{kt}r_t)$: I think the differential notation is unfortunate and confusing. I go through the Vasicek model derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964695/itos-lemma-2nd-order-term-notation/3964861#3964861), but it uses Ito's lemma. Your worries about how to treat the "operator" $d$ are justified: one cannot really integrate "both sides with respect to different variables", but in cases such as this, when it coincidentally "works", people abuse the notation.

Comment: Okay, thanks. My assistant told that I cannot think of this in the way I proposed (the same approach as I wrote above). He said that $d/dt$ is not a fraction and hence I cannot just multiply by $dt$. He said that I should instead think of Ito's lemma to get it right. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I linked an answer showing Ito's lemma in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at your Ito's lemma -approach and it's good. However, to be sure, my logic in the math above is not sound after all? So you agree with my assistant in the sense that I cannot arrive at the answer by just multiplying by $dt$?

Comment: Treating the differentiating operator as a fraction is not correct, but it sometimes leads to the correct answer. I will try to think of an example when it doesn't work. In general, I'd discourage treating differentiating operators as fractions and instead invest time in learning the underlying maths the proper way, i.e. integrating factor technique for ODEs, Ito's lemma for SDEs, etc.

Comment: Good advice indeed. Thanks a lot again!